Telescope stops working after too many instances
I am getting used to a nvim + tmux setup when I noticed Telescope suddenly delivered no results, outside currently open vim files for the current tmux window.
I have 5 windows open, telescope works fine in window 1, but does not work in window 5.
It also works in new tmux session.
Healthcheck says all is OK.
How do I debug this? Any clues?

I’m having trouble understanding your question: please provide a sequence of steps that you take, what you expect to happen, and what actually happens.
